# Liking feature implementation using two API's via client side as IOS app (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, tastypie

We are trying to build a simple follow feature for our IOS app. We have two API's our `Brand API` with an array of objects containing unique brand ids for our brands within each object. And our `Firebase API` where we store users. Within the `Firebase API` it has a key called followingBrands with and array of objects called composed of the `unique brand ids from our`Brand API`  as keys with the value true. The objects are created once a user has followed the brand from liking the brand on our app.

When the app loads we check to see if `Firebase API`'s brand ids keys matches the `Brand API`'s brand ID then show a star to indicate the user is already following the brand.

Our problem is `Brand API` is implemented with pagination, (i.e. offset), so how will we verify all brands they are following if not all the unique brand ids will be available to compare with our `Firebase API` ?

We use swift on the IOS side. And the `Brand API` is built using django-tastypie

**Firebase API**

```
"user_id" : {
  "currentFollowingCount" : 0,
  "displayName" : "",
  "email" : "",
  "followingBrands" : {
    "unique_brand_id" : true
  },
  "provider" : "Facebook",
  "userID" : "user_id"
}
```

**Brand API**

```
{
  "labels": [
    {
      "id": "unique_brand_id"
    }
  ],
  "meta": {
    "limit": 10,
    "next": "/api/?limit=10&offset=10",
    "offset": 0,
    "previous": null,
    "total_count": 33
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do a trick just show the star whenever there is a brandID equals to you fireBase followingBrands key. you don't need to check it in brandAPI as i think you already insert every brand followed by user in the fireBaseAPi so this will work for you.

```
 let fireBaseResponse:[String:AnyObject?] = [
                        "followingBrands":["unique_brand_id":true]
                        ]

let customObject = ["customObjectBrandID":"unique_brand_id"]//yourObject

let followingBrandsArr = (fireBaseResponse["followingBrands"] as! [String:Bool]).keys

//now do a check for Star
let myObjectBrandID = customObject["customObjectBrandID"]
if followingBrandsArr.contains(myObjectBrandID!) == true{
    print("user is following this brand so show the follow star")
}else{
    print("don't show or hide it")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not really clear what you're trying to accomplish to be honest. The Brand API doesn't do a lot, or? Or is it translating between internal ID's and unique brand ID's? If so, why?

As a simple problem solution you could turn off pagination, according to your output of tastypie there are only 33 records in your set, so setting a limit either via the `Meta` class, e.g. `max_limit = 1000` or when calling the API resource via `?limit=1000` should return all objects. If they don't change much you should probably apply some caching.